# Including bundled code from one project into another with Typescript support

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, monorepo

I'm working on a project that has two subprojects: let's call them `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`. These are completely different projects, but both are written in Typescript and use webpack as bundler.

During development, I would like to use some parts of `ProjectA` in `ProjectB`, but overall requirement is that `ProjectB` must consume all code from `ProjectA` as an external dependency - via script tag, and not via npm installation or such.

So my thoughts would be to bundle the code of `ProjectA`, using library option of `webpack`'s output configuration property, host the resulting bundle somewhere, and include it in `ProjectB` via script tag. But since I would use some of functions from `ProjectA` during development of `ProjectB`, I would like to have `Typescript` benefits as well.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Those requirements seems like a mess, high coupling, low testability, easy circle dep; can't you split your project in more than two projects? Lerna/Bits is what you could be looking for

Comment: Too easy with webpack references and externals.

Answer (score 1):

Create two subfolders, `/a/` and `/b/` then use [aliases](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) to easily reference b from a:

```
// webpack.config.js
 module.exports = {
  //...
 resolve: {
   alias: {
    b: path.resolve(__dirname, '../b/')
   }
  }
};
```

Then you can easily import between the parts as:

```
  import Something from "b/something";
```

> but overall requirement is that ProjectB must consume all code from ProjectA as an external dependency -

Then add another webpack file to `/b/`, build b externally as a [library](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-librarytarget)  and add it as an [external](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) to a:

```
 externals: {
   b: "b"
 }
```